# Why does setting $Assumptions make my Fourier transforms slow?

Tags: performance-tuning, fourier-analysis, assumptions

Consider these Fourier transforms

```
FourierTransform[Exp[-I ω0 t] (Exp[-(t)^2]), t, ω]; // AbsoluteTiming
FourierTransform[Exp[-I ω0 t] (Exp[-(t/T0)^2]), t, ω]; // AbsoluteTiming
FourierTransform[Exp[-I ω0 t] (Exp[-((t + τ)/T0)^2]), t, ω]; // AbsoluteTiming
FourierTransform[Exp[-I ω0 t] (Exp[-((t - τ)/T0)^2] + Exp[-((t + τ)/T0)^2]), t, ω]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.022893,Null}*)
(*{0.167016,Null}*)
(*{0.051487,Null}*)
(*{0.183451,Null}*)
```

It's pretty fast, but if I setting the assumption, then it becomes much slower

```
$Assumptions = T0 > 0 && ω0 > 0 && τ > 0;

FourierTransform[Exp[-I ω0 t] (Exp[-(t)^2]), t, ω]; // AbsoluteTiming
FourierTransform[Exp[-I ω0 t] (Exp[-(t/T0)^2]), t, ω]; // AbsoluteTiming
FourierTransform[Exp[-I ω0 t] (Exp[-((t + τ)/T0)^2]), t, ω]; // AbsoluteTiming
FourierTransform[Exp[-I ω0 t] (Exp[-((t - τ)/T0)^2] + Exp[-((t + τ)/T0)^2]), t, ω]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.018221,Null}*)
(*{6.465289,Null}*)
(*{9.765310,Null}*)
(*{48.956260,Null}*)
```

Why does the performance decrease a lot? And is there a way to use the global assumption while maintain the performance?

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for the editing. English confuses me more than Mathematica :)